Getting Loader exception property error on adding Nuget packages
I have added some new Nuget pakages to my existing project. But after adding i get this LoaderException property error. On Exception i see it is not able to find the assembly reference but assemblies are present in the references also in the project file. 



This question is similar to: Error message 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
